# how to pull received time from all emails in outlook mailbox

Tags: vba, datetime, outlook

I have most of this worked out already, but need assistance. I want to store all of the received times of the emails from various outlook folders.  All of the folders are inside the same folder so I have an array to go through each of these.  I need the times stored into a variable that I can then display in or write.console.  There will be hundreds of times to display. The variable is Totalmsg that I want these times stored in, then displayed once complete.

```
Sub EmailArrivalTimes()
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim MailItem
Dim EmailCount() As Integer, arrNames


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

arrNames = Array     ("Andrew", "Ashton", "Becca", "Beth", "Bree", "Brittany", "Cecilia", "Chance", "Christina J.", "Christine", "Dustin", "James", "Jeff", "Jenni", "Jennifer W.", "Josh", "Josie", "Kara", "Lisa", "Megan", "Misti", "Nathan", "Paul", "Sam", "Shane", "Shawna") 'add other names here...
ReDim EmailCount(LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames))

For x = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center"). _
        Folders("Onshore - " & arrNames(x)).Folders("completed")
On Error GoTo 0

ArrivalTime = 0

Dim Totalmsg

If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
       Totalmsg = MailItem.ReceivedTime
Next
End If


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are overwriting the value of `TotalMsg` at each iteration in this loop:

```
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
       Totalmsg = MailItem.ReceivedTime
    Next
End If
```

You will want to append to it, instead:

```
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
       Totalmsg = TotalMsg & vbCRLF & MailItem.ReceivedTime
    Next
End If

Debug.Print TotalMsg 
     'Note: this will likely exceed what can fit in the console window, _
     ' but you can instead write the string to a text file/etc.
```